# endorse/like someones mysites skills sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-part, mysites

I was just wondering if anyone was aware of anyway/any webpart on mysites where you can endorse a persons skills/knowledge. Kind of like linkedin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a user in SharePoint the set of `Skills` are stored in the `User Profiles`. And `MySites` pull such data from the User Profiles of each user.

If you open the `Central Administration` site. And GoTo the `User Profile services`. Its noticed there is list of OOB `user profile properties`, and `SPS-Skills` (*the internal name for Skills*) is one of those properties which is responsible for holding a users set of skills.

So the answer is, you do not have any OOB solution or webpart which can be used to endorse a person's skill.

**What you can do**: Create a custom `User Profile Property`, based on your requirement analysis which is capable of storing the mappings between skills and respective endorsements by other users. This new `User Profile Property` can then be used to show on your MySites